# Exactly one solution to integral equations

Tags: functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Show $\exists$ exactly one solution $U\in C([-1,1])$ to the intergral equation

$U(x)=x\int_{0}^{x}t^{2}cos(U(t)) dt $ for $x \in [-1,1]$

**Attempt**

I think I can use the contraction mapping theorem for this to prove there exists a unique fixed point and hence a unique soloution if I define $AU(x)=x\int_{0}^{x}t^{2}cos(U(t)) dt =U(x)$ so I want to show $\|{AU-AY}\|\leq k \|U-Y\|$ for $0<k\leq1$.

I get $\sup_{x\in[-1,1]}\bigg|x\int_{0}^{x}t^{2}(cos(U(t))-cos(Y(t)))\bigg|$

$\leq\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}(cos(U(t))-cos(Y(t)))dt$

I'm not sure how to get rid of the $t^{2}$ to get the results I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the norm $|| \cdot ||$ on $C([-1,1])$ is the $ \max - $ norm.

For $a,b \in \mathbb R$ we have $|\cos a- \cos b| \le |a-b|.$ This gives

$\int_{0}^{1}t^{2}|cos(U(t))-cos(Y(t))|dt \le \int_{0}^{1}t^{2}|U(t)-Y(t)|dt$

$ \le \int_{0}^{1}t^{2}||U-Y||dt= ||U-Y||\int_{0}^{1}t^{2} dt= \frac{1}{3}||U-Y||.$

Comment: Should not be $\mathopen|\cos a-\cos b\mathclose|\leq\color{red}{|a-b|}$?

Comment: Oooops , you are right

Comment: Thanks, for proving that U is differentiable is it possible to use the uniform contraction theorem? If so I'm not 100% sure how I should define $A(U(x),\beta)$ in this case.

Comment: @Roger By definition U is continuous on [-1,1]. Use now the equation - differentiate both sides/use fundamental theorem of calculus - to deduce that $U$ is of class $C^1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Vert Tu - Tv \Vert_{\infty} =\sup_{x \in [-1,1]} \vert Tu(x)-Tv(x) \vert \le \int_0^1 t^2 \vert \cos u(t)- \cos v(t)\vert  \, dt
$$
$$ 
\le \Vert u - v \Vert_{\infty} \int_0^1 t^2 \, dt = \frac{1}{3} \Vert u-v \Vert_{\infty}
$$
being the cosine function $1$-Lipschitz. Then you conclude by Contraction fixed point Theorem.